# Finding which physical key was pressed in PreTranslateMessage

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, keyboard

The problem I'm trying to solve is finding out whether a pedal attached via USB was pressed. The pedal is actually a single key keyboard, mapped to the key B.

Problem is that PreTranslateMessage gives me the Unicode value of the key, so if the language bar is set to a different language, say Hebrew, I get the Unicode value of whichever letter is mapped to the key B, say the letter Nun in Hebrew.

The code I'm using is

```
BOOL CViewerDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
        if (pMsg->wParam == 'B')
            videoSwitch();

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

When the language bar has English selected, wParam contains hex 42 (= capital B), when Hebrew is selected, it contains hex e7, indicating a Unicode character is passed as if it was a keystroke.

Is there a way to find out which physical key was pressed?

Maybe mapping the key on the pedal (2nd keyboard only) to some other key?

Maybe identifying from which keyboard the key press originated?

Comment: So your question is actually: _I have two USB keyboards connected to my computer. When I receive a WM_KEYDOWN event, how can I determine on which keyboard the corresponding key has been pressed?_

Comment: @MichaelWalz: actually, I don't care on which of the two keyboards the user pressed the key B, as long as I know it is the key B.

Knowing the key is on the 2nd keyboard (which has only one key) would a solution, but not the only one.

Also, the primary keyboard might not be USB. It might be a laptop's integrated keyboard, or connected via PS/2 connector to a desktop.

Comment: Somebody could explain the close- and downvotes here ?

Comment: Use the scancode section of the `lParam`?

Comment: Or use the [Raw Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) to differentiate input from specific devices.  The generated key messages do not carry very much identifying information, but the `WM_INPUT` message does.